# Trying to output into a text file the encrypted or decrypted file

Tags: c, encryption

Something goes wrong into the while loop but I really don't get it why.It was supposed to print the encrypted or decrypted result of a file into an output file with the argument (progname.exe -e input.txt)

The problem is that there is no output file created with the encrypted or decrypted code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c;
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *output;

    if (argc < 2) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (strncmp (argv[1], "-d", 2) == 0) {

        output = fopen (argv[5], "w+");

        while (fscanf(fp,"%x",&c) != EOF)  {
            c = c >> 2;
            c = c-200;
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }

    if (strncmp (argv[1], "-e", 2) == 0) {

        output = fopen (argv[5], "w+");

        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
            c = c+200;
            c = c << 2;
            printf("%04x ", c);
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Its currently opening a text file and it either encrypts or decrypts it depends on the user

Comment: The problem is that there is no output file created with the encrypted or decrypted code

Comment: You don't open the file fp. You look for argv[5] for the name of the output file. This may be well beyond the number of arguments you provided. I guess you mean argv[2]. Fix the argc check then. You never write into output. You write to standard output (screen). etc.

Comment: When I implemented in  my code the arguments it stopped printing the encrypted or decrypted code though

Comment: Oops saw you open fp. But you use argv[1] to get its name. At the same time `argv[1]` should be "-e" or "-d". Your program should have 3 arguments (`argc == 4`). `argv[1]` is "-e" or "-d", `argv[2]` is the name for fp, and `argv[3]` is the name for output. Fix that first. To write into output file use `printf(output, ...)`. Try first to simply copy fp into output without changing the text and get this working.

Answer (score 0):

The order/number of program parameters doesn't seem to make sense.

The program seems to expect the input file as it's first parameters (`argv[1]`):

```
} else if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If that first parameter isn't an existing file, the program will exit without writing any output.

Later the same parameter is compared to `"-d"` and `"-e"` to check for decryption/encryption:

```
if (strncmp (argv[1], "-d", 2) == 0) {
```

Probably you meant to use the program parameter *after* the input file name, `argv[2]`? The program won't write any output file if that parameter isn't `-d` of `-e`.

Additionally the fifth parameter `argv[5]` is taken as the output file name. If that isn't a valid file name, no output file will be created either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you code mostly is improper use of command line arguments.

The `argc` contains the argument count so if you have `ls -a -l file` then the `argc` will contain value `4`, with this information you can parse the command line arguments inside your program using `switch` case easily based on the number of arguments passed, alternatively you can look into the command line parser libraries.

- **getopt() / getopt_long()** (`#include <unistd.h>` from the POSIX C Library), which can solve simple argument parsing tasks, the getopt built-in of bash is based on Getopt from the GNU libc.
- **Argp** (`#include <argp.h>` from the GNU C Library).

Here is an example with switch case using you code,

it can take command line arguments line.

Output to file:

```
prog.exe -e input.txt output.txt
prog.exe -d output.txt input2.txt
```

Output to stdout:

```
prog.exe -e input.txt
prog.exe -d output.txt
```

for other arguments it will print an invalid argument error and returns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c;
    FILE *input = NULL;
    FILE *output = NULL;
    int encryption = 1;   // Flag to set encryption/decryption.

    switch ( argc ) {
    case 3:
        if ( strchr(argv[1],'-') != NULL ) {
            if ( argv[1][1] == 'e' ) encryption = 1;
            else if ( argv[1][1] == 'd' ) encryption = 0;
            else {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: invalid Option %s\n",argv[1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if ((input = fopen( argv[2], "r")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: Cannot Open %s\n",argv[2]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            output = stdout;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: Invalid arguments\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if ( strchr(argv[1],'-') == NULL || 
             strchr(argv[2],'-') != NULL ||
             strchr(argv[3],'-') != NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: invalid argument\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            if ( argv[1][1] == 'e' ) encryption = 1;
            else if ( argv[1][1] == 'd' ) encryption = 0;
            else {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: invalid Option %s\n",argv[1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if ((input = fopen( argv[2], "r")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: Cannot Open %s\n",argv[1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if ((output = fopen( argv[3], "w+")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: Cannot Open %s\n",argv[3]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
       }
       break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Invalid arguments\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Do encryption and decryption based on the flag.
    if ( encryption ) {
        while ( fscanf(input,"%c",(char*)&c) == 1 ) { // Do encryption
            c = c + 200;
            c = c << 2;
            fprintf(output,"%x ", c);
        }
    } else {
        while ( fscanf(input,"%x ",&c) == 1 )  { // Do decryption
            c = c >> 2;
            c = c - 200;
            fprintf(output,"%c", c);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```